# RStudio stopped reading accents after update

Tags: r, file, encoding, rstudio

I updated Rstudio and a few packages a few days ago. Now, I wanted to run a script that I usually run bi-weekly, but now it cannot read the files due to accented folder names. Previously I had no problem reading these folders. Here's the code:

```
wd <- "C:/Users/name/Opinião/"
# Get all questionnaires 
filenames <- list.files(path = paste0(wd,"Questionarios/"), pattern="*.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
```

Now I get an error in `Opinião`. The system is unable to read the accent. If I try to access the folder manually, I get `"C:/Users/name/OpiniÃ£o"`. I'm not sure what the issue could be since it worked before the update, and LOCALE corresponds to Portuguese. I could manually change the folder's name, but then the files also have accents, and it would be a bit time-consuming doing it manually.

Any ideas? Here is `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Portugal.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Portugal.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Portugal.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Portugal.1252    
system code page: 65001

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] readxl_1.3.1      sjmisc_2.8.5      lfactors_1.0.4   
[4] stringr_1.4.0     lubridate_1.8.0   data.table_1.13.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7       magrittr_2.0.1   insight_0.10.0  
 [4] tidyselect_1.1.0 lattice_0.20-41  R6_2.4.1        
 [7] rlang_0.4.12     fansi_0.4.1      dplyr_1.0.7     
[10] tools_4.0.2      grid_4.0.2       utf8_1.1.4      
[13] DBI_1.1.1        ellipsis_0.3.2   assertthat_0.2.1
[16] tibble_3.1.6     lifecycle_1.0.0  crayon_1.4.2    
[19] purrr_0.3.4      vctrs_0.3.8      sjlabelled_1.1.7
[22] glue_1.4.2       stringi_1.5.3    cellranger_1.1.0
[25] compiler_4.0.2   pillar_1.6.5     generics_0.1.0  
[28] pkgconfig_2.0.3  zoo_1.8-8
```

The problem seems to be with folder and file names as I can write in R

```
> name <- "Opinião"
> name
[1] "Opinião"
```

**Update**: The problem is only using RStudio.

Comment: Have you tried File --> Reopen with Encoding in the RStudio menu?

Comment: A simple [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in _Python_ for its intelligibility): `"Opinião".encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'OpiniÃ£o'`.

Comment: Thank you both! I tried changing the encoding, reopening. Restart the computer but nothing works. This is the folder name so changing the encoding only for this word wouldn't work as filenames are read through `list.files`. If I try on the terminal I have the same issue with opening folder names with accents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everyone. This problem happened to me, today. I spend some time trying to fix it, but was worthless. Curious thing, at the files panel the files names was correct, but just when I have to put the files names as strings the problem occurs. Well, I updated the R base and Rstudio and the IDE turned back to recognize the names accents. I don't know why some of then still have problems, but the most recent ones is working well.

Comment: Thank you! This new update also solved my issue. I updated RStudio and I no longer have this issue

Answer (score 0):

You're probably hitting this issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1045, fixed in RStudio just a few days ago. If you want to pick up a preview build with the fix, you can get it here:

https://dailies.rstudio.com/

Alternately, you might be able to work around the issue by manually marking the encoding on the returned filenames, like this:

```
wd <- "C:/Users/name/Opinião/"
# Get all questionnaires 
filenames <- list.files(path = paste0(wd,"Questionarios/"), pattern="*.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
Encoding(filenames) <- "UTF-8"
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help. Your code doesn't work since the problem is that RStudio doesn't recognize accents, so filenames is empty. I've tried to play with encodings but gave up and run the code in R. I've updated the latest daily build, using the link provided but the problem remains. Maybe I forgot to change some definitions, I'm not sure. The problem is only in RStudio though.